# Extending Laravel 5 PasswordBroker so that I can use another email function

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to use my own method for the **emailResetLink**, because I want to send emails with styling and I'm using *CssToInlineStyles*.

---

First I tried extending the **PasswordBroker**:

- in **PasswordController** changed use *Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker* to *App\PasswordBroker*
- created new empty class, that extends the PasswordBroker

  ```
  namespace App;

  use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker as PasswordBrokerBase;

  class PasswordBroker extends PasswordBrokerBase {
  }
  ```

And I got this error (the newly created class is empty):
**Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider] is not instantiable.**

---

Then I tried to create contextual binding with:

```
$this->app->when('Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker')
        ->needs('Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer')
        ->give('App\Services\Mailer');
```

But nothing happened (it still uses the old Mailer).

Any ideas of how can I achieve the goal?

Comment: For customization view of email you can edit `resources/views/auth/password.blade.php`

Comment: My "other" mailer also uses the same password.blade file, but it converts all css to inline styles. That's why I need separate method to be called (in which I use the mentioned CssToInlineStyles on the password.blade template).